# iOS - Object is not added to array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, uisearchbar

I don't understand why the attachment is not added to the array`filteredAttachments`?`dataAttachment` is the one that has attachments and I want to search in it for attachments that have a specific name and then those that match to be added to

**.h:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * dataAttachments;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * filteredAttachments;
```

**.m:**

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {

  self.filteredAttachments = [NSMutableArray new];

  [self.dataAttachments enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(Attachment *attachment, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([attachment.name containsString:self.searchBarFiltern.text]) {

      [self.filteredAttachments addObject:attachment];

    }
  }];

  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `self.dataAttachments != nil`?

Comment: Explaining @trojanfoe 's answer : Did you alloc-ed + init-ed `self.dataAttachments`? Also check same for `filteredAttachments`

Comment: Yes. I am sure. I am adding attachments to it in another method

Comment: (lldb) po self.dataAttachments.count
3

Comment: OK cool.  Now are you sure the filter text is contained within one more names (including exact letter case)?

Comment: I think [tableview reloaddata]; method called before your block execution

Comment: I tried the self.searchBarFiltern.text to be exactly as the attachment.name

Comment: Once put [self.tableview reloadData]; method in your block after if condition and check the result

Comment: Add     NSLog(@" At: %@ Str: %@ ",attachment.name,self.searchBarFiltern.text); before checking if( string contains)

Comment: unfortunately moving [self.tableview reloadData]; didn't work

Comment: I've put the nslog inside the block, just before the if  At: Anfrage Kamer Str: Kamer

Comment: thanks for the replys and sorry for taking your time. Apparently the problem was that I was doing self.filteredAttachments = [NSMutableArray new]; in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

First of all initialize your self.dataAttachments array

```
self.dataAttachments = [NSMutableArray array]:
```

and then check what is output of self.dataAttachments array whether it is blank or filled.

Answer (score 1):

The containsString: method was only added in iOS 8.
If you want your code to work on iOS 7 as well as iOS 8 you should use one of the rangeOfString calls instead. Basically if the range returned has a length of zero, the substring is not there.

```
if([string1 rangeOfString:string2].length >0)
{
  // found
}
```

Comment: Thanks. apparently the problem was that I was doing self.filteredAttachments = [NSMutableArray new]; in the wrong place.